# How do I setup a unit test user for django app? The unit test can't login

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-authentication, django-testing

I've enabled login authentication for my django app.  Unit tests for views are not working because they get stuck at the login page.  Setting a breakpoint immediately after the view's response is returned and using

> print response.content

results in output that contains the phrase 'please login'

How do I setup a user so the testcase can login?  I've tried using my username and password, but it doesn't work in the unit test context.

Answer (score 46):

The following code inserted at the beginning of the testcase creates a user, logs them in, and allows the rest of the test to contiue

```
self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser', password='12345')
login = self.client.login(username='testuser', password='12345')
```

Comment: @rurp you're exactly right.  I changed the answer to reflect your comment.  Thanks for removing another line from my code!

Comment: What if a user with that username exists in the DB? What would happen in tests?

Comment: The documentation suggests, and my tests used a separate DB for testing so this didn't come up. I'd assume you'd get an error back from create_user.